# Could icomma conflict with siunitx?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, incompatibility, siunitx, icomma

I'm also having the problem with the space after a comma in decimal numbers (like discussed here: [German language: use of comma in numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/german-language-use-of-comma-in-numbers))

and I wonder if I can use both the `icomma`-package (which seems to be quite old) AND `siunitx` together.

I'm not sure if that makes sense, but I have a large writing project (Ph. D. thesis) which already contains a lot of numbers. 
With `siunitx` I'd have to use the `\num[]{}` command for each one of them and I would not dare to replace something like that automatically, so I'd have to check each single number - that's impossible at the moment.

So I'd like to at least have an automated solution for the numbers used in math mode and that should be `icomma` - right?

My only concern is, if both packages could create a conflict - is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry, be happy. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$2,33=\num{2,33}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, the `\num` macro in `siunitx` was never intended to replace simply using math mode. It's there for cases where you want more complex formatting _or_ where you may need to alter formatting for a single source (such as switching between `,` and `.` for decimals depending on the country of publication).

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks! So I'm glad to hear (if I am not mistaken), that there is no negative interaction between `icomma` and `siunitx` possible