# best practice international template

Tags: best-practices, babel, microtype, font-encodings, input-encodings

I would like to have a template which can be internationalised (i.e. is suited for latin script languages) and uses the microtype package.  I suppose that we therefore need the following packages:

- babel (we can always set it to english)
- inputenc (for using international characters)
- fontenc (for printing international characters correctly)
- lmodern (since fontenc changes the font, we want to change is back)
- microtype (better looking text)
- possibly csquotes

Below is the document now, please provide suggestions for improving the template e.g. the sequence in which the packages are called.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're going to be accommodating non-latin scripts, it's probably best to set things up for XeLaTeX rather than LaTeX. this means replacing `babel` with `polyglossia`. It will also require otehr changes to your list of packages but I can't remember exactly what now.

Comment: I would recommend loading `inputenc` after `lmodern`, otherwise some characters can be incorrect (e.g. `\textbackslash`). As well, it is really unclear what do you mean by "internationalised", please try to make clear what are your intentions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments. I changed the order of inputenc and lmodern. With Internationalised I mean, for other languages which use latin scripts.

Comment: @tohecz `inputenc` has nothing to do with output encodings; it *reads* some files depending on the loaded output encodings, but LaTeX eventually relies on `fontenc` to assign the meaning to `\textbackslash`. `lmodern` says nothing about `\textbackslash`.

Comment: @bquast There's no `T1` option to `lmodern`.

Comment: @egreg I always mess up these, you're right of course.

Comment: @tohecz There is no problem with `fontenc` either, as `lmodern` doesn't make any assumption on the output encoding (maybe there used to be some glitches at the beginning with Latin Modern, IIRC).

Comment: @egreg, so the order of inputenc, fontenc and lmodern doesn't matter?

Comment: I usually recommend `fontenc`, `inputenc`, `babel`, font packages. But it's not really relevant for languages using the latin script.

Comment: Ok, I'll just stick with that to make it as universal as possible. Could you mention what the reason or intuition for this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cleveref` complicates it a bit. You must pass the desired language(s) either to the `documentclass` or directly to `cleveref`. Furthermore it does not work together with polyglossia's version of `\selectlanguage{}`.

`csquotes` supports `\selectlanguage{}`, but states in its manual that "polyglossia support is currently in a preliminary state".

So until better support for polyglossia my documents looks like this:

```
\documentclass[english,danish]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[kerning,spacing,babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{danish}
...
```

Now I don't have to edit my preamble every time I want to switch language. It even support switching language during a document.

Answer (score 5):

Since the decimal separator can be different in different countries (either a full stop or a comma), I will suggest that you either add the [icomma-package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/icomma) or adapt the code from *Claudio Beccari's* article in [The PracTEX Journal, 2011, No. 1](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2011-1/beccari/Intcomma.pdf).

Another `intelligent comma`-package is [ncccomma](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools), which, according to the author and other sources I found on Internet, is even smarter than `icomma`. According to its documentation:

> The solution used in this package is more expansive (*i.e. compared to icomma. My comment*) because we compare the next
>   character with up to ten decimal chars. But this solution needs less number of
>   spaces to be inserted into original document (the space is only necessary in the
>   place of a comma delimiting something and a decimal number).

I am not aware that these packages should be loaded in any specific order (before `hyperref`, of course).

You should also consider to add the [siunitx-package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx). See this link at tex.stackexchange.com: [German language: use of comma in numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18673/9632).

(`microtype` should have the option `babel=true`?)

Comment: Good point, Dutch (and most other European languages) also does this. Which is the proper place to put those?

Comment: According to the manual, the default value is `babel=false`. So use `babel=true` or just the shorthand `babel`.