# a4paper, where should I declare it? In document class or geometry?

Tags: best-practices, paper-size, geometry, package-options

I currently have an `article` document class and I previously changed it to include printing on A4 paper:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
```

However, I had to change my margins to meet my university requirements and the answer I received used A4 in the `geometry` package too.

```
\geometry{a4paper,margin=15mm,bindingoffset=25mm,heightrounded,}
```

Partially practical and partially theoretical, is there any difference to using either declaration and/or is there an effect by using both?

Comment: It's irrelevant: options to the class are automatically passed to all loaded packages.

Comment: @egreg: If you specify the paper size via `\documentclass` and don't use `geometry`, the paper will be of the correct size, so something changes. The question is, could these changes interfere with `geometry` in any way? (It doesn't seem like it.)

Comment: @doncherry The class understands `a4paper` and sets the text block dimensions accordingly. If you also load `geometry` the dimensions are changed again according to `geometry` default for A4 paper, unless you use the `pass` option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`a4paper` specified in document class will be passed to  `geometry`. So there is no difference **in your case** if you specify the option in `\documentclass{article}` or `\usepackage{geometry}`.

However if other packages need to know document format, you need to specify `a4paper` in the document class.

Comment: Looking at the source for the article class, how is the paper size being passed to geometry? I only see that `paperheight` and `paperwidth` are being directly set.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit `! LaTeX Error: File `a4paper.sty' not found.`

Comment: Passing the option to ``\documentclass`` gives any package a chance to react to the option; on the other hand, passing it to ``\usepackage{geometry}`` doesn't, thus I wouldn't say there is no difference. It depends on what other packages do with the paper size. Nothing in most cases, but who knows...

Comment: There is a difference if you call `a4paper` as class option or only `geometry` option. Please see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472270/16550

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the changes, but I think the standard way is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
...
```

You can specify the margins further. The simplest way is writing

```
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: no, add `a4paper` to the `class options`, it only passed on to `geometry` then any later package that might also react to `a4paper` would never see it.

Comment: @daleif I don't understand your comment sorry...

Comment: type `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{...}` not just `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}`

Comment: @daleif I just realized but if that's true, how is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @daleif No answer? :P

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong in there is a difference. If package A and B can both react to option O, then passing O to A does not tricker option O in B. Passing O to the class instead, then even if the class does nothing with O, it is automatically passed on to both A and B.

Comment: Here is a very simple package for you, make an A and B version and test for yourself: `\ProvidesPackage{A}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
  \typeout{A: a4paper tricker}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax` Having `a4paper` added to the class trickers both A and B, giving it only to A (and not the class) does not tricker B.

Comment: The prime example, now I think about it, is the `draft` option. Sometimes you want this for all packages (`graphicx` and `listings` reacts to it), other times only local to the one package

Answer (score 4):

There might be a difference if you load some other packages that could use `...paper` options. It is naturally global option of your manuscript so I think it is better declared global, similarly to the language options discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60298/11002

So I think that `...paper` should be put as a global option of `\documentclass`.