# What's the correct syntax for accents?

Tags: accents, syntax

I've found that writing "Sáenz":

```
S\'{a}enz
S\'aenz
S{\'a}enz
S{\'{a}}enz
```

Produces the same output.

It gets even trickier when you have two accents in a row, such as in "comunicação" (portuguese):

```
comunica\c{c}\~{a}o
comunica\c{c}\~ao
```

(and perhaps some other combinations (?))

What is the correct syntax, and why?

Comment: Why bother? Use a UTF8 encoded source file and enter all accents directly.  See [How to type special/accented characters in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8858/2693).

Comment: if you must stick with the original accent codes, it's better to avoid braces, as those suppress kerning between letters in a word.  in particular, if an accent code is a single non-alpha character, it isn't necessary at all to use braces to keep the pieces distinct; this form is unambiguous to tex.

Comment: The exception to the rules put forward by Alan Munn and Barbara Beeton arises if you use BibTeX. For BibTeX (but not biblatex/biber), it's best to use the *third* form you provide, i.e., `S{\'a}enz`. That way, the author's surname will be sorted as if it were written as "Saenz", i.e., without an accent. Conversely, `Sáenz` will be sorted by BibTeX *after* `Szabo` -- probably not what you want, right? See [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/5001) for more on this.

Comment: Also see / duplicate?: [Automatically change é to \'e – most convenient setup for accented letters?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97233)

Comment: Thank you all guys, I'm really not having any problems as of now (I'm actually on Alan Munn's side on this: why bother if there is utf8 encoding), I just got curious because I use BibTeX and I had some issues with accents before.  I just wanted to set the record straight.  @Mico has a very strong argument for `S{\'a}enz` though, but so does Barbara Beeton for avoiding the braces...

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the link, but I'm not actually looking to write the characters (after a couple of years with LaTeX one kind of gets how to fix these minor "challenges"), I'm just wondering which is the proper way to do it and most importantly, what advantages one version can give me over any other (see Mico and Barbara's messages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking into consideration what was stated by Alan Munn, as long as there is `utf8` encoding in your text, you can just write the words normally and just forget about the accents.  e.g:

```
\documentclass{report}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Sáenz e Comunicação
\end{document}
```

However, as stated by Barbara Beeton, **IF** you **MUST** stick with the explicit syntax, then avoid the `{}` braces, since those suppress kerning between letters in a word, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
S\'aenz e Comunica\c{c}\~ao
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, Mico pointed out a really important issue when using `Bibtex` (but not biblatex/biber): it's best to use: `S{\'a}enz`. That way, the author's surname will be sorted as if it were written as "Saenz", i.e., without an accent. Conversely, `Sáenz` will be sorted by BibTeX *after* `Szabo`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to bother, BibTeX is completely incapable of UTF-8 (whoever says otherwise, is sadly mistaken. The various "BibTeX replacements" are more pain to set up than they are worth, and in my experience plain don't work). The most reliable source to date has been [this](http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/pack/bibtex/btxdoc/btxdoc.html) (extra)official BibTeX documentation.

In the body of the text, use UTF-8. It looks much nicer, the friendly language teacher next door can also correct your worst mistakes that way.

For BibTeX, in your `.bib` files use `{\'o}` and so on, even if told `\'o` "works the same" (it doesn't!). BibTeX considers `{\somefunkymacro L}` to be an `L` (to be handled as such for sorting purposes) with some fancy `\somefunkymacro` accent (the braces are critical here). This makes some nice tricks possible, i.e., define a `\noopsort` macro to be able to give an entry like:

```
@Book{lHopital96:_analy_infin_petit_lignes_courb,
  author =       {{\noopsort{Hopital}}de l'H{\^o}pital,
                  Guillaume Marquis},
  title =        {Analyse des Infiniment Petits
                  pour l'Intelligence des Lignes Courbes},
  publisher =    {Paris},
  year =         1696
}
```

This sorts like `Hopital`, without mangling the good marquis' name in the bibliography.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "BiBTeX replacements", but `biblatex/biber` is part of TeX Live/MikTeX and can handle UTF8 `.bib` files with correct sorting without much fuss (at least for all Latin script languages). Whether or not this is an appropriate route for any particular person depends on a lot of other factors, but I wouldn't characterize `biblatex/biber` as "not working".

Comment: Isn't it about time for everyone to use BibLaTeX and biber (especially those with little or no investment in BibTeX)?

Comment: BibLaTeX is BibTeX for all intents and purposes here. I do have extensive experience (some 30 years now) coaxing random pieces of software into working (on our Suns I built gcc, X and TeX from scratch as there was no other way to get them), biber was my biggest failure to date. It is just an abandoned half-finished prototype, not a product.

Comment: Your use of the `\noopsort` macro, while certainly nifty in its own rights, is a serious distraction from the main point -- viz., how best to enter an "accented" letter -- that the OP raises and you aim to answer. Please consider providing a simpler example.

Comment: @vonbrand Just a slight correction, `biblatex` is in no way a replacement for `bibtex`, since the former is a LaTeX package, and the latter is a program for sorting and formatting bibliographies. I'm sorry to hear you've had difficulties with `biber`. Perhaps this was some time ago.  There are many of us who use it routinely without any problems, and it is far from abandoned (in fact one of the developers [PLK](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1657/plk) is active on the site).

Comment: Yes, a bit concerned to hear it is abandoned since I'm the sole developer and there has hardly been a week without a commit (sometimes hardly a day) for years. It is actively developed and bug-fixed, has a robust build farm I use for releases and has been used without problem by hundreds of people via TeXLive for a couple of years. It's basically a drop-in replacement for bibtex when used with biblatex and has no current open issues or bugs. It is fully UTF-8 compliant (Unicode 6.1) and can do CLDR-aided very complex sorting. I have no idea where @vonbrand is getting his information from.