# A comma decimal separator that is bigger than a dot

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, icomma

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Check:\\
with "," $0,125$\\
with "." $0.125$

with commas:
\begin{equation}
P=
\begin{bmatrix} 0,1 & 0,3 & 0,0 & 0,6 \\
                0,2 & 0,4 & 0,1 & 0,3 \\
                0,0 & 0,8 & 0,0 & 0,2 \\
                0,2 & 0,0 & 0,2 & 0,6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

with dots:
\begin{equation}
P=
\begin{bmatrix} 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.6 \\
                0.2 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.3 \\
                0.0 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.2 \\
                0.2 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As you can see numbers with a comma as a decimal separator are wider than those with a dot. How can I change space after a comma to be equal to space after a dot?

Comment: See also [German language: use of comma in numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18673).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need an `intelligent comma`-package like [icomma](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/icomma) or [ncccomma](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ncccomma).

You can also adapt the code from *Claudio Beccari's* article in [The PracTEX Journal, 2011, No. 1](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2011-1/beccari/Intcomma.pdf).

Add

```
\usepackage{icomma}
```

or

```
\usepackage{ncccomma}
```

to your preamble.

If you have none of those packages installed, you can add Claudio Beccari's code to your preamble (I have removed the comments and added `\makeatother` as the last line):

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\punctcomma}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\decimalcomma}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode‘\,="8000}
{\catcode‘\,=\active \gdef,{\futurelet\let@token\m@thcomma}}
\def\m@thcomma{\let\@tempB\punctcomma
\@tfor\@tempA:=0123456789\do{%
    \expandafter\ifx\@tempA\let@token\let\@tempB\decimalcomma
    \@break@tfor\fi}\@tempB}
\makeatother
```

Hopefully, this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what intelligence is hidden in the mentioned intelligent packages, but I guess that it can be implemented by the four lines:

```
\def\mathcomma{\futurelet\next\mathcommaA}
\def\mathcommaA{\mathchar`, \expandafter\ifx\space\next\,\fi}
{\catcode`,=13 \global\let,=\mathcomma}
\mathcode`,="8000

without space after comma: $1,234$ with spaces: $1, 2, 3$.

\bye
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the code in `icomma.sty`.

Comment: The `icomma.sty` uses sequences `\ProvidesPackage`, `\AtBeginDocument` and many `@` like sequences. This makes the macro file format dependent. My macro is format independent (as usual). This is substantial difference.