# Switching decimal mark between comma and dot

Tags: typography

You might know that in large part of continental Europe, decimal mark is comma instead of dot.  I am writing a really **huge** document and I would like to switch between them easily from one point, e.g.

```
\newif\comma
\commatrue

\ifcomma{
???
}

\pi = 3???14
```

I am aware that all decimal mark dots should be replaced by something else, but what?  I am opening contest for a *most elegant* solution for the problem.

Comment: Does this need to be a plainTeX solution? The [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) already offers a much better alternative to type-setting numbers.

Comment: Do you want the input source to switch to using comma (because someone else wrote it perhaps) or do you want the input to keep using `.` but the output use a comma or both input and output to change or...

Comment: Perhaps take a look at for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/german-language-use-of-comma-in-numbers.

Comment: Does not have to be plain tex.  I just didn't found any other suitable keyword - e.g. there is no latex keyword.

Comment: siunitx seems like a fine solution, but that package loads 10 different other packages... I worry that this could largely decrease the speed of compiling my 200 page document!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example sets the numbers in math mode. That allows an easy "redefinition" of the comma or dot to produce a dot or comma.

Syntax:

- `\num{...}` takes a number with dot or comma and outputs the number according to switch `\ifnumcomma`.
- If `\numcommatrue` if active, then `\num` outputs a comma, with `\numcommafalse`, the output is a dot.

The definition can be used for both plain TeX and LaTeX. The example contains a testing part for plain TeX:

```
\mathchardef\NumMathCodeDot=\mathcode`\. %
\mathchardef\NumMathCodeComma=315 % \mathord, not \mathpunct

\newif\ifnumcomma

\def\num#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \ifnumcomma
      \mathcode`\.=\NumMathCodeComma
      \mathcode`\,=\NumMathCodeComma
    \else
      \mathcode`\.=\NumMathCodeDot
      \mathcode`\,=\NumMathCodeDot
    \fi
    \ifmmode
      #1%
    \else
      \mathsurround=0pt %
      $#1$%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

% Testing (plain TeX)

\numcommatrue
\num{3.14} + \num{1,23}

\numcommafalse
\num{3.14} + \num{1,23}

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The font for the number is taken from math mode.
- If `siunitx` is available, use it, because it is much more powerful and configurable. Then `\num` can be left in the code, but the definition then comes from `siunitx`. And `\num` is configured there.

Comment: You might want to name the main user macro something else than `\num` since this name is already widely employed by users of the `siunitx` package.

Comment: @Mico: That was the reason for the name. If the user loads `siunitx` (why it is not available for plain TeX?), then he does not need the code of this answer, because `siunitx` is much more powerful.

Comment: OK, you may want to flag this deliberate parallelism explicitly, e.g., by indicating that this command shouldn't be used if the `siunitx` package is loaded. Regarding the non-availability of `siunitx` for PlainTeX, I suspect that Joseph Wright can/should give the authoritative answer. :-)  I suspect, though, that it might have something to do with much of the code in `siunitx` being written in LaTeX3...

Comment: I'd say this is the most elegant solution regarding my original request.  Therefore I will accept it, despite the fact I will actually use `siunitx`.  I found it so powerful, I will risk even longer compilation of 200 page document.

Answer (score 9):

Decimal numbers in TeX can be input either with a period or a comma:

```
\hsize=10,5cm
```

is understood as well as

```
\hsize=10.5cm
```

However, this is about decimal numbers passed to TeX when required by its syntax rules. *Printing* numbers is a different matter, because TeX will print whatever you decide to.

So, if you define

```
\def\PI{3.14159}
```

and type `\PI` in your document, TeX will dutifully output

> 3.14159

In order to ensure uniformity across your document, you have to input your numbers in a different way:

```
\newif\ifcomma % starts as false
\def\cp{% comma or period
  \ifcomma{,}\else.\fi
}
\def\PI{3\cp14159}

The number $\PI$ is an approximation to $\pi$.

\commatrue

The number $\PI$ is an approximation to $\pi$.

\bye
```

[image]

If you're using LaTeX, there are a few options available; the best is using `siunitx` and its `\num` command that will typeset its argument according to what options you have selected.

Answer (score 5):

Use siunitx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
you can even use comma \num{123,45} or dot \num{123.45}
\end{document}
```

just change `{.}` to `{,}`. You might also want to use `group-separator={.}` when using `output-decimal-marker={,}`. The default group-separator is a thin whitespace.