# Math spacing decrease

Tags: spacing

Is it possible to decrease the default spacing in a decimal number between the colon and the first decimal point, i.e. the spacing between "," and "8" in the number $5,8$? (this is the greek notation I use). My editor says that it is large enough and it should be decreased. Of course I can use the known combination "\!" but there are thousands of decimal values and it is too difficult. Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you mean you want the effect of `$5{,}8$` ? If so I'm sure this must be a duplicate, I'll see if I can find an answer

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133910/switching-decimal-mark-between-comma-and-dot

Comment: Are you familiar with the [icomma](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package? It treats commas encountered in math mode as decimal separators (instead of as a math punctuation characters).

Comment: icomma is amazing! It solved all the spacing problems at once! thanks!