# Commas in spanish mathmode using libertine leave unwanted space

Tags: libertine, spanish

I'm writing in spanish, where a comma is used instead of a point as a decimal separator. When using libertine as a font I get that the comma leaves a space a bit too wide to the right:

[image]

Is it only me who's annoyed? Am I doing something wrong? Here's a MWE. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Here is the tenth part of one: $0,1$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used to use `0{,}1` for decimal numbers in Portuguese language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [German language (and some other European languages): use of comma in numbers as decimal marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/german-language-and-other-central-european-languages-use-of-comma-in-numbers) Basically, be sure to load the [icomma](https://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package.

Comment: @Sigur - Do look into the capabilities of the [icomma](https://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package.

Comment: @Mico, nice to know that `i` stands for *intelligent* not for an Apple comma... lol Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should load babel and use dots for decimals:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Here is the tenth part of one: $0.1$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Umm, in some European languages, commas rather than periods are commonly used as the *input* decimal separator.

Comment: @Mico, In Spanish today both are allowed, but commas are the traditional separators, and this is why by default babel change the dot by comma but there options to change this.